# wxPython GUI-wide settings

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I have both a fundamental and technical wxpython question regarding GUI settings that are common to, and accessed by, many aspects of a single GUI.

In the interest of saving time I haven't cut/paste huge swathes of example code but I will explain it in words. I don't think I lose any clarity by doing so but shout if I do.

I have a wxpython GUI whose main feature is a notebook featuring many pages, the majority of which are data plots. Each page is defined according to unique class and while each class is different, they all access the same underlying data and are therefore fundamentally connected. Given this connection, there are some settings within the GUI that are common to all pages within the notebook. For example, the definition of the colour or shape of points on the various plots. Such settings may be used to define how the data is displayed e.g. car data may be red squares while bus data may be blue triangles.

Given that the plots on each notebook page are defined in separate classes, I could just repeat these definitions in each class. However, this feels like code duplication and since the colour/symbol definitions should be common across all plots, it feels like these definitions should be at the top GUI window level not at the notebook page level.

I have tried placing attributes within the top level window and I can access them from within a notebook page class using something along the lines of:

`self.GetGrandParent(self).mySymbols`

Where GetGrandParent is a crude way to work up the hierarchy of page /notebook / panel etc up to the main window. There may actually be more levels to traverse than just two.

My question is, is there a better way or more pythonic way to define GUI wide settings or attributes, once, at the top level (eg main frame) but access them from lower levels (eg notebook pages)?

Comment: If the classes live in separate files you should create a module (separate file) where you store constants and import it into those files when necessary.

Comment: The classes all exist in the same file

Comment: I may be missing something here, but what is to stop you defining these in their own class or (in danger of stirring up the python purists here) declaring them as globals.

Comment: what about this? when the data is ready, compute the common parameters once in the main class and spawn these classes with the common parameters passed as arguments.